# How to let a datagridview automatically generate new rows to fill the empty space

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView `dgv` in a Form which is re-sizable. It would be great if I can let it automatically generate some rows to fill, if any, empty space. For example, if I have the `dgv` like this (3 rows):

```
-------
|  1  |
-------
|  2  |
-------
|  3  |
-------
```

If I drag the bottom border down (enlarge it), instead of getting some gray space without even empty rows:

```
-------
|  1  |
-------
|  2  |
-------
|  3  |
-------
|     |
|     |
-------
```

I hope to get this (two more automatically generated rows):

```
-------
|  1  |
-------
|  2  |
-------
|  3  |
-------
|  4  |
-------
|  5  |
-------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        while ((dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0) || (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height * dataGridView1.Rows.Count < (dataGridView1.Height - dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight)))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(/*Your generated row information*/);                
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.
Felipe Campos
São Paulo - Brazil